# Android Studio Request App Permissions cant compile shows error: array dimension missing

Tags: java, android, compilation

When trying to compile Android studio code I get the following error: array dimension missing

[error: array dimension missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3MZC.png)

```
    public void showCamera(View view) {



        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) ==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                showCameraPreview();


        }else {

            if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Camera permission is needed to show the camera preview.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            requestPermissions(new String[]Manifest.permission.CAMERA), REQUEST_CAMERA);
        }

    }
```

}

Comment: you're missing a curly brace to close your onCreate()

Comment: You should check out some java tutorials to get the basics right. What you do here is declare a method in a method.
`onCreate(Bundle)` is a method which hosts it's code in curly brackets. `{}`

You declare another method inside `onCreate(Bundle)` before the closing `}`. So move your `showCamera(View)` method outside of  `onCreate(Bundle)`.

Comment: i followed u,and now it shows error: array dimension missing

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
public void showCamera(View view){
     ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                        MainActivity.this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                        CAMERA_REQUEST );
}
```

then you need override onRequestPermissionsResult

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
if(requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST){
            if(grantResults.length >0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                callCamera();
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Camera permission is needed to show the camera preview.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return;
            }

 super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
 }
```

fun calCamera()

```
 public void callCamera()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        intent.putExtra("aspectX", 0);
        intent.putExtra("aspectY", 0);
        intent.putExtra("outputX", 250);
        intent.putExtra("outputY", 200);
    }
```

and override ononActivityResult

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
 if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  }
```